# How do I get intervals classes (groups) from a histogram of data?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dataset

in my problem setting, I have data for 1 variable. The data is numerical, and in my problem setting, I just generate a frequency count of the data, for example:

If data is:

[image]

I create a frecuency count like:

```
4.9: 1
5.0: 2
5.5: 1
...
8.2: 1
```

I end up with a barplot, where xlabel is the measurement (but it is actually a numerical number), and the value is the frequency count, such as the following:

[image]

What I want to obtain, are ranges/intervals, which better represents my data. Let me elaborate on this, I know I want to split these data in 4 (four) intervals. The data in these intervals, should be around the peaks (high frequency counts), because these physically should be similar (in my case the data is thickness).

We can think this as a clustering problem, and the clusters should be around peaks (look at the plot). I already tried [Jenks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization) method, but it seems that it does not fit my problem, because mine is kind of frequency count related. Is there a technique to solve this particular problem? Maybe this is already solved, but I cannot find specifically the solution for this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "better represents my data" might mean?  What aspect(s) of the data do you want represented and how do you want us to determine what a better representation would be?

Comment: Done, I have added some description on what do I expect.

Comment: It sounds like Jenks' method might do exactly what you are looking for.  Could you perhaps show us specifically how it fails to meet your expectations?

Comment: Why do you want to form groups? That is rarely a good idea.